# Refactoring many jQuery Ajax calls - best practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a lot of JavaScript/ jQuery code blocks to handle asynchronous
data processing in my page. Each code block has three functions (code is incomplete and for illustrative purpose only):

1. encapsulates `$.ajax` call:

   ```
   function doSomething(data){

     // do some preprocessing 

     $.ajax({}); // some JQuery Ajax operation that accepts data

     // do some postprocessing
     return false;
   }
   ```
2. handles the response:

   ```
   function handleResponse(result){  
     // process the result
     return false;
   }
   ```
3. handles any error:

   ```
   function handleError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
     // gracefully handle the Error and present relevant information to user
     return false;
   }
   ```

In a page that requires a lot of data processing I end up having a lot
of these blocks which seems to be duplication, so I decided to do some
refactoring.

I figure there would be different ways to go about this.

1. One could have one error handler that can be reused across Ajax calls (obvious).
2. One could maybe reuse some response handlers, but this would be akward as responses are very different depending on call.
3. Maybe create some kind of prototype object that provides base functionality and have a static method for error handling (can this be done in JavaScript?).

I was just wondering if anyone has come across this and/or if there is a best practice solution for this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the $.ajaxSetup({}) method in jQuery to setup some common ajax settings.

For instance, if you are going to be posting to the same URL over and over again on some page, you can just set that in the ajaxSetup. This would mean you would have to pass less parameters to a function like what Richard provided. Any property of the ajax method's first parameter can be set as a default in $.ajaxSetup().

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: 'my/ajax/url'
    success: function() {
        // Do some default stuff on success
    },
    error: function() {
        // Do some default stuff on a failure
    }
    // etc...
});
```

They can be overridden in any ajax call. So, now you can just do:

```
$.ajax({data:{foo:'bar',bar:'foo'}});
```

And you can override the URL, for instance like this:

```
$.ajax({url:'different/ajax/url',data:{foo:'bar',bar:'foo'}});
```

Comment: Specifically says on https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/ that you shouldn't use this as it affects plugins.

Answer (score 7):

We have often used a wrapper function for the Ajax call in order to simplify the usage so you could do this:

```
function NewAjax(url, data, success)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      fail: function ()
      {
        // Do generic failure handling here
      }
}
```

But I often prefer to bind to every ajax event using the jQuery ajax events:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

so you could bind to every failure or success of every ajax call such as:

ajaxError( callback )
ajaxSuccess( callback )

Comment: much appreciated! To be fair I think KyleFarris has the most elegant solution so I gave him the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

As Richard shows, look at what is different between the code snippets and pass them in as parameters to a function. Javascript can pass functions around as parameters, which can get rid of a great deal of redundancy.

If the url doesn't change though, then why pass it in as a parameter, you could have a global variable that will have the main part of the url, and just pass in the part of the url that changes.